# Displaying next sampling time date and time without freezing WPF form in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, dispatchertimer

I am writing a code in WPF & C# to display next sampling time in Date and time format.
For example, if sampling time is one minute and current time is 08:00 - the next sampling time should show 08:01, Next sampling time is displayed once 08:01 has passed.

I have tried using dispatcherTimer and sleep thread.
But when I use the whole WPF form freezes until next update.

Could you please help me?

code ->

```
 public float samplingTime = 1;
        

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
            tboxSampling.Text = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(samplingTime).ToString();
            void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)samplingTime*1000);
                tboxSampling.Text = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(samplingTime).ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You should not be using `Thread.Sleep` at all.  Simply modify your timer interval or skip timer ticks.  If you want to wait without blocking the thread you could also use `await Task.Delay(...)`.  But that's unnecessary here.  The whole point of a timer is to fire X often.

Comment: No need to sleep. The `Tick` is fired every `Interval` although note that accuracy may not be great so you may skip seconds

Comment: This seems to work correctly `code`  //timer to display sampling time in time window
            tboxSampling.Text = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(samplingTime).ToString();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(samplingTime);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
            void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                
                dtEnd = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(samplingTime);
                tboxSampling.Text = dtEnd.ToString();
                running = true;
            }

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) for such a problem:

```
public float samplingTime = 1;

public MainWindow()
{
    dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tboxSampling.Text = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(samplingTime).ToString();
}
```

> Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs.